# CSS styling not working when uploaded to server?

Tags: css, styling

I've created a basic page, from a template I had for the rest of my site, but pulled most of it apart to make the page look "not designed". It only has an unordered list with a short paragraph fixed to the top and a logo float right. It works in system preview, but when uploaded to the server it loses all the CSS styling.

This is the html:

```css
#title {
    width:400px;
    position:fixed;
}

#icon {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}

h5 {
    font-size:25px;
    color:#ff6682;
    line-height:1.35em;
}

a:link {
    color:#253b84;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>/other</title>
      <link href="assets/scripts/AMK_Website.css" rel="stylesheet"              
         type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="icon">
         <img src="assets/images/icon/icon.gif" width="80" height="106" alt=""/>
      </div>
      <div id="title">
         <h5> /other is a collection of personal work in design photography, as    
            well as work that inspires me. To get back to
            the important stuff, <a href="index.html">click here</a>
         </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="photolist">
         <ul>
            <li><img src="assets/images/other/1.jpg" width="768" height="1024"        
               alt=""/></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: No code, no help. We don't go "outside" to look at problems.

Comment: There is a box above the text area that should be code block. Just hover over them and a tool tip should show you which one then the rest is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Did you use an absolute link to your CSS file? This might be one explanation it works locally, but not on the production system, your link path is most probably different on there.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: Check the CSS file path that you have includes. path varies from local and server

Comment: What's the URL of your site once uploaded?

Comment: The CSS file works fine for other pages on the site, which is whats causing my confusion. The URL is adammckiernan.ie/other.html

Comment: That's normal, given the way you are linking to your CSS file ... It will not work for all .html files except if they are all located in the same folder as the "assets" folder.

Comment: Check your `console.log` to see if your `CSS` file is having a 404 error

Comment: Can you share the link.

Comment: adammckiernan.ie/other.html

Comment: I don't get your problem, your .css file works fine on the page.

Comment: From what I can see on both Chrome and Safari none of the styling is working on the page? Thanks for all the help, I'm new to web design and trying to understand.

Comment: Yes, the css included in your post is missing in the CSS file, that's the problem. Add it to the file. The CSS file itself is included perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Paul, that worked! I just realised any changes I made to the Template pages was only in the html and not in the CSS, and that the CSS has to be re-uploaded with the changes, I guess I thought that the CSS changes would upload with the page. Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: No problem at all, everyone started with simple problems at the beginning. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your css isn't where the html link expects it to be. If you're pointing to a file in `assets/`, make sure that folder is in the same directory as your html file, and make sure it contains that specific css file.

Comment: He is including the file just fine, his CSS rules just don't exist in that file.